# Laravel 5.6 Specific Table Migration

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

when i run this command it says nothing to migrate

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2018_11_30_093512_create_task_user_table.php

Nothing to migrate.
```

And this is the task_user migration file

```
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('task_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

can u help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked whether that migration has been run before?

Answer (score 3):

Create a sub-folder under migration folder and move/copy that specific migration file to that sub-folder and run `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/sub-folder/` command.It will migrate all the migration files that will be resides in that sub-folder.

Answer (score 2):

It means, You can migrate a file only once, If you want to make changes, you should create another migration file then run `artisan migrate` command. To `rollback` and `migrate` the same file again, use `migrate:refresh` command like this.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Comment: @Banjuran Balendrakumar i run that command. but this table not created in the database and it again says nothing to migrate